# Managing differences in Ubuntu and CentOS features when deploying app

Tags: ubuntu, centos, php

We have a problem that our programmer uses Ubuntu to develop advanced php application (advanced because he installs many extensions/seperate databases/utilities) and the problem is that whenever he installs something new, we also have to install it on centos, and centos have very old repositories, and because of that there are times when we fail to install some of those features on centos server (because compiling is not always an option due to too many failed dependencies).

Is there a way to check/sync versions of utils between servers so that our programmer will only be able to use utils that are possible to install on centOS?

Comment: The repositories in CentOS aren't *old*, they are *stable* and predictable, and are kept up to date with security fixes. In my world, stability and robustness are more important then always having the latest features. Tracking the latest software versions [introduces dependency problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell#Problems) which don't always have a clear benefit to the business. It's better to upgrade software per a business plan then at the whim of the upstream developers.

Comment: Note that if desired, the RHEL/CentOS [Software Collections ( SCL ) Repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) provides and updated versions for certain packages like PHP, MySQL, Python. These are tested and *stable*. Also consider the (EPEL repo)[https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL]. Both of these are reasonable compromises between the stable (older) base packages and the desire to have newer software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is DevOps *gone awry...*

I would really insist that the developer use an environment that mirrors your production environment or intended target systems. CentOS/RHEL and Ubuntu have different priorities as Linux distributions,  but the onus is on the developer to ensure compatibility of applications.

In order to make this easier, would it be possible for the developer to use a CentOS virtual machine or to perform their work in a test/dev environment within your infrastructure?

Comment: Seriously, this.  Your development environment should be as close to production as humanly possible.

Comment: +1 I often hear that 'DevOps' mean that Operations should adopt more of a development mindset. But it's important to note that DevOps requires that *developers* adopt more of an operational mindset. Software must be developed and tested with the expectations that it will be deployed to production. Developers cannot throw their software over the fence and make it your problem.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, I think that will be easiest thing to do, to create an VM for him